# Adding custom methods to Sequelize Model

Tags: node.js, express, model, sequelize.js

I'm trying to add a custom method to a Sequelize model. Here is my code:

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Form extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            // define association here
        }

        // attempt 1
        static testing() {
            console.log('testing');
        }
    }

    // attempt 2
    Form.prototype.testing = function() {
        console.log('testing');
    }

    Form.init({
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        identifier: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'Form',
    });

    return Form;
};
```

I have tried it these two ways. Here is how I'm calling the method:

```
const Form = require('../models/Form');
Form.testing();
```

Both ways return the same error, "TypeError: Form.testing is not a function". What is the proper ways to add a custom method?

Answer (score 0):

The example module exports a function to initialise and return the model, not the model itself.

```
const formInit = require('../models/Form');
const Form = formInit(sequelize, DataTypes);
Form.testing();
```

The static method form will work.

```
class Form extends Model {
    static testing() {
        console.log('testing');
    }
}
```